# Доступ к динамически созданному TextBox (WPF)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-phone-8.1

Есть примерно такая разметка:

```
<Page
    x:Class="Project1.TestPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
    xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
    xmlns:media="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Media"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="#f4f4f4"
    RequestedTheme="Light">
    <Page.Resources>
        <!-- Шаблон элемента списка -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="List_Item">
            <Border Background="#fff">
                <!-- TextBox'ы, значение которых необходимо получить -->
                <TextBox PlaceholderText="{Binding value}"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <!-- Список, который будем тиражировать -->
        <ListBox x:Name="MyList"
                 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource List_Item}"
                 Background="Transparent"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

После некоторых расчётов в `behind-code` мы получаем:

```
MyList.ItemsSource = new object[] {
    new {value = "One"},
    new {value = "Two"},
    new {value = "Three"}
};
```

Число элементов заранее не известно.
Моя проблема заключается в том, что я не знаю, как получить пользовательский ввод в `TextBox`. Пробовал:

```
foreach (var item in MyList.Items) {}
```

но в `item` лежит объект привязки, а не `ListBoxItem`.
Присваивание имени `x:Name` `TextBox`'ам эффекта тоже не даёт. 

*P.S. Второй мини вопрос: в процессе работы мне показалось, что `ListBox` не слишком хорош для такой задачи, нужно много действий и стилей по-умолчанию отключать. Есть ли контрол, которому просто можно передать разметку и `ItemSource`, после чего он просто растиражирует её (разметку), реализовав тем самым список элементов, без функционала вроде выделения и прочего?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел решение данного вопроса. Переписываем чуть `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding value, Mode=TwoWay}" PlaceholderText="{Binding p_value}"/>
```

И теперь в любое время в `value` лежит значение, указанное пользователем.